# I have a lot of numbers that need to be moved to another column without disturbing the numbers in the column they are being moved to

Tags: excel

I am looking to get all numbers in one column. Lets call it column D (each row has other information that needs to stay in place)

Currently a lot of numbers are in column D although some of the cells are blank.

I need the blank cells to be filled with a number that is in a different column but the same row.

Example:

I need the blank cells in lets say column D row 7 to be filled with the number that is in column G row 7.

I know how to copy and paste and that would take be days to sort out.

I’d like a process that can do this without needing to go through all of the rows individually to do the task.

So the Question:

Is this possible?

If so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Add a blank "Helper" column in your worksheet. Enter this formula in its first row (here presumed to be row 2).

```
=IF(COUNTA(D2),D2,G2)
```

The formula will look at D2. If that cell has no content, copy that content to the helper column, else take the value from G2.

Copy down as needed. Then copy / paste special > Values in place. This will replace the formulas with the values they produced. Finally, copy the helper column to your column D and delete the helper. - Done.

Comment: I think I can do that, im real new here. One question though. my D column have 5477 rows and id say a third of the numbers are in  column G. in that case does this formula still work?

Comment: Yes. It would work for a million rows, too. When selecting a large range to paste a formula, select the cell in which you entered the formula and click Copy (Ctl+C). Then, `Home>Find & Select > GoTo`, and type the range you want to paste to in the `Reference` field. Click *OK* and then *Enter* to complete the pasting. Use the same method to copy/paste values.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I have not been able to accomplish the task. I created a blank column (is this the same as a helper column?) and put this into it: =IF(COUNTA(TRIM(D2)),D2,G2) and it gives me a value of 0

Comment: My bad. Here are my apologies. COUNTA doesn't accept the embedded TRIM function. I have removed it from my answer.